# Symfony2 - using form validation in REST API project

Tags: api, validation, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

In a Symfony REST API project and we are implementing a validation for the params passed to the end points.
I'm trying to using forms for this purpose but they don't seem to work as expected.

Given this end point as example:

```
GET /users/
```

which accepts a **companyId** as param

we want that this param is required and integer.

**The controller**

```
public function getUsersAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();

    $form  = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user, array(
        'method' => 'GET'
    ));

    $form->handleRequest();

    if ( ! $form->isValid()) {
        // Send a 400
        die('form is not valid');
    } else {
        die('form is valid');
    }
}
```

**The form type**

```
class UserType extends FormType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder->add('companyId', 'integer');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ApiBundle\Entity\User',
            'csrf_protection' => false

        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return ''; // if this is not empty, the form is not submitted at all
    }
}
```

**The validation.yml**

```
ApiBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        companyId:
            - Type:
                type: integer
            - NotBlank: ~
            - NotNull: ~
```

**The config.yml**

```
framework:
    validation:      { enabled: true, enable_annotations: false }
```

**The Problem**

$form->isValid() in the controller is always true

Comment: Where did you save the `validation.yml` file?

Comment: in src/ApiBundle/Resource/config/
I think the file is loaded, as if I use the validator service straightly, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace with

```
$form->handleRequest();
```

to

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: That would throw an exception, as handleRequest instanciates a NativeRequestHandler, which requires the $request param to be null

Comment: @Wminded what you mean "which requires the $request param to be null"?

Comment: the method has this check:    if (null !== $request) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($request, 'null');
        }